# Change ion-backdrop opacity?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to change the opacity of my `ion-backdrop` from `0.08` to `0.33`.

I've tried:

```
ion-backdrop {
  opacity: 0.33 !important;
}
```

and setting `$popover-ios-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);`.

Setting the value on `ion-backdrop` does work but since it's important, it doesn't animate the fade out.

How can I change the opacity of the backdrop?

Comment: Did you place your css in app.scss?

Comment: @Duannx Yes, I did..

Comment: So it has to work. Can you re-produce your problem at stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 5):

I know I am a bit late to this party, but now with Ionic 5, you have a CSS selector that will do the job for you. That is mentioned in [their documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#css-custom-properties) as well.

So basically all you could do is, initialize the modal and style it in your SCSS file.

This is my *component.ts* file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
// ModalComponent is just a normal angular component, your path may vary
import { ModalComponent } from '../../modals/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: './some-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-component.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponentComponent {
  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
  ) { }

  async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalComponent,
      cssClass: 'modal-class'
    });

    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

and my *component.scss* file:

```
.modal-class {
  ion-backdrop {
    --backdrop-opacity: 0.33;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve do it using the cssClass property in alertController (Ionic 4)

```
  async alertError(message: string) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'alertClass',
      animated: true,
      header: 'Error',
      message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }

 ion-alert {
   &.alertClass{
     background: rgb(0,0,0,.8);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that this `ion-backdrop` question it's related with the **Ionic Alert Controller**. If that is the case than you need to apply CSS inside the `global.scss` (Ionic 3) file or `theme\variable.scss` (Ionic 4/5). This is required because `ion-backdrop` lives in the app as an **Ionic Global Component**.

Therefore find the mentioned file inside your Ionic project. It's usually in this directory *app > src > global.scss*.

Now let's suppose that we have this **Alert Controller** instanciated in some page class.

```
...
async serviceErrorAlert() {

    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'try-again-alert',
      ...
    });

    await alert.present();
}
...
```

As you can see this **Alert Controller** haves a CSS class of `try-again-alert`.
So to add all custom CSS that you want just go the style file and add your own style.

`global.scss` (Ionic 3):

```css
.try-again-alert {
    --background: rgba(55, 67, 77, 0.9);
}
```

`theme\variable.scss` (Ionic 4/5):

I strongly recommend you to use CSS `background` attribute and `rgba()` property. With this approach you can now choose the color that you want (first three numbers) and the opacity of the color (fourth number).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9105) about this in Ionic's GitHub. The only workaround listed there that doesn't break the animation is long and complex - too much to list here. A direct link to the solution: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9105#issuecomment-375010398

Answer (score 0):

I only managed to do it in Ionic 5 by using `background: rgba()` property with a desired alpha value.

*Page where modal is called*

```js
openModal(): Promise<void> {
    return this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: ModalPage,
        backdropDismiss: true,
        cssClass: 'custom-class'

    }).then(modal => {
        modal.present();
    });
}
```

*`app/theme/variable.css`*

```
.custom-class {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /*black with 0.8 opacity*/ 
}
```